# HR make false promises before joining

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, careers, employment-agreement, employee-engagement

I'm from India. I joined my new organisation 1 month ago.

Before joining recruiter/HR make promises that I will be working on the specific tool I’m only interested in but after joining manager and director both are forcing me to give the client interview if I got selected I will have work with client on their tool.

I have the written communication about the specific tool I will be working on but director/manager say that you did’t understand clearly what recruiter mentioned before joining.

Ultimately they have said that I will have to work else will have to put resignation.

HR communication screenshot before joining are attached below.

Please advice me what can I do?

Comment: What country? Labor laws vary by location.

Comment: What written evidence do you have? Is that matched by the contract you signed? Then what country as some are better than others…

Comment: "Ultimately they have said that I will have to work else will have to put resignation." Vikash, I do not know where you are located, but in the US, you do not resign, you let them fire you. In the US at least, that's usually the only way you receive unemployment benefits. In any case, knowing which country you're in would be helpful. Without knowing that, we can't really give you good advice.

Comment: I'm from India and my company provides Advertising services.

Comment: Looks like the recruiter made it safe for themselves by always answering mostly. Mostly is a fluent value that is different from person to person so nothing that is set in stone.

Comment: @Vikash does your contract state that you will only be working on that tool and never anything else? I am relatively 100% sure it doesn't.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I would advise the opposite.  If the employer fires you then that  is a black mark on your CV.  If you resign, then its a softer issue.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly - you may want to edit that screenshot a little more, you've blanked out your name, but the recruiter refers to you by name (or the other way around).

Secondly - Although I don't know Indian Law per se and am not a lawyer - I am **extremely** skeptical that a LinkedIn conversation, especially one that seems to be as informal as that one would be accepted as proof of breach of contract.

Thirdly - I've known some workers to have a strong preference to using a specific tool or set of tools, but to go as far as to say 'I will only use X tools' seems to me to be excessive. I mean, I could appreciate something like 'I only develop in Java' or 'I only use MySQL', however Business needs change and someone who 'only works in MySQL' might occasionally need to use Postgres or MSSQL.

To get some form of Breach of contract - you'd need first a Contract that says 'I will only use XYZ' - which I'd be well surprised if it did, to get a breach of contract in employment law would be a pretty tall order.

If it were me and I started on a position that was nothing like what I thought it was, I'd start looking elsewhere and just hand my notice in when I had something lined up.

Comment: I don't want to put resignation, should I start working with the client on their tool and parallely start looking for new job?

Comment: So it their way until you have something better lined up. Among other things, you may find that their way isn't bad.

Answer (score 5):

Just do what you have to do to earn money while you find a more suitable job.There is no need for drama with these people, they don't have the work to give you with your tools of preference.